# Is there a way to "map" multiple files into a single file, without writing to disk or RAM?

Tags: files, filesystems, security, encryption, merge

I've been thinking about different ways files could be hidden, and while encryption is excellent at hiding the contents of files, they're not really good at hiding the fact that files exist. In the case of encrypted volumes, a monolithic file or device/partition filled with randomness is a noticeable indication of an encrypted filesystem. Steganography is not a viable alternative for large amounts of data, but perhaps splitting a drive image into multiple randomly-sized "fragments", and spreading them throughout an actively used drive could work.

To recreate the drive image, one could imagine of mapping the fragments into a single file, one after another, to read and write from.
An option to achieve this would be to concatenating the files on disk or on memory, but this would create either a duplication of data, or excessive amounts of RAM, respectively.

A solution I've attempted is to mount all these fragments as loop devices, and creating a RAID array from them, but this solution gets very slow very fast, at least on my PC.

Thus, I've been searching for a way to create a device file that redirects reads and writes to the underlying disk image fragments, while keeping the solution usable in terms of performance.
Even though I've found [mergefs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs), which merges multiple directories into one, what I'm looking for is a way to merge multiple files into a single file.

While I'm aware that this could be achieved by creating a special device through a kernel driver, or implementing a custom filesystem through FUSE, I'd like to avoid undertaking these significant tasks if possible. Is there any pre-made solution to achieve what I want?

Comment: Interesting idea.  I don't know of anything that already does this, but FUSE seems like an ideal approach.

Comment: Relevant: [Steganographic file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganographic_file_system)

Comment: Indeed. While I've considered using both StegFS and Rubberhose, I couldn't get them to work on my machine. While I could keep trying, their poor storage efficiency means I'd prefer an alternative if possible. I've looked towards other possible methods, but found nothing so far.